# How do you enable parallelization support for random forests in OpenCV 2.4?

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

I am running OpenCV 2.4.13.

I am using CvRTrees.train() and CvRTrees.predict() for a classification application.

Currently, the CvRTrees.train() function only uses one CPU core. I can see this in htop: one CPU is at 100% and the others hover around 3% when train() is called.

The docs says you have to explicitly enable parallelization support, so I have rebuilt the libaries with OpenMP support and reinstalled. However, the behavior is the same. Only one CPU is utilized by train().

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Are my expectations inaccurate?

Here are the steps I use to build and install:

Enabled OpenMP in cmake

```
$ mkdir release && cd release
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_OPENMP=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF ..
```

Make and install

```
$ make && sudo make install
```

Run ldconfig so that the linker cache gets updated

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Rebuild my program and run `ldd` on the executable to ensure that it's using my newly installed libraries in /usr/local/lib

```
$ ldd ./build/release/classify | grep opencv
libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4 (0x00007f6e9d525000)
libopencv_ml.so.2.4 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4 (0x00007f6e9d29e000)
```

Another note: If I add syntax errors around line 261 below, the build breaks, so I know I have the correct compiler flags set.

```
modules/core/src/parallel.cpp
-----------------------------
259 #elif defined HAVE_OPENMP                                                                                                
260                                                                                                                          
261         #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)                                                                       
262         for (int i = stripeRange.start; i < stripeRange.end; ++i)                                                        
263             pbody(Range(i, i + 1));
```

Another note: ldd tells me that my application links libgomp.so, so I am reasonably sure that OpenMP is enabled.

Comment: [Maybe useful](http://answers.opencv.org/question/79567/does-opencv-functions-really-use-openmp/)

Comment: I cheated and built multiple small forests, one per core. But tbh that was possible because I implemented the production forest code myself. It could merge multiple forests.

Comment: @MSalters That's a perfectly acceptable solution. In fact I would  prefer it. But it wasn't obvious to me how to combine training results from multiple trees. Any hints?

Comment: Walk the OpenCV trees, copy each tree to my own forest. Each tree node has a split dimension, a split point along that dimension and two children. Not too complex.